# htaccess RewriteRule Redirect with R,L,E flags (environment variable)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, environment-variables

i want to set a apache env variable after redirection from htaccess

`RewriteRule ^somelink/$ /somelink.php [L,R,E=HOWTO:ok]`

`[L,R]` flags because i want to change address in browser address bar
`[E]` flag because i want to set variable

`[E=HOWTO:ok]` should set the variable but nothing happend

i tried var_dump($_SERVER) on somelink.php after redirection but any HOWTO appears
but if i use `SetEnv HOWTO ok` everything is ok

### how to set apache environment variable with [R,L] redirection and get it in php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to set apache environment variable with [R,L] redirection and get it in php file?

You can't set an environment variable, redirect the request and have it still be there when the second request is made. When you use `R`, it redirects the browser, meaning *an entirely new and separate request is made for the new location*, which in this case is `/somelink.php`.

You'll need to handle this differently, maybe with a GET parameter?

```
RewriteRule ^somelink/$ /somelink.php?HOWTO [L,R,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i want use env to get rid of get but it is another story, anyway thanks

Comment: Note that since you're passing through the broswer again with `GET`, then the `GET` values can be tampered/removed by the client, while server-internal `ENV` variables cannot be directly changed by the client